# stdio.h and FPU errors in Neovim using clangd LSP

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller, neovim, clangd

I have a stm32f103 project that is initialized using stm32cubemx and I'm using neovim for editing and arm-none-eabi-gcc for compilation of code (whit auto-generated makefile).

I also have installed [clangd](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#clangd) LSP and also [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) to generate `compile_commands.json` file. Everyting works fine except that there's two errors:

1. stdio.h file not found
2. Compiler generates FPU instructions for a device without an FPU (check __FPU_PRESENT)

I looked at `core_cm3.h` file and `__FPU_USED` is disabled, which is exactly what clang says.

```
/** __FPU_USED indicates whether an FPU is used or not.
    This core does not support an FPU at all
*/
#define __FPU_USED       0U
```

But I couldn't find any line in my makefile flags that enables the FPU for compilation.

```
# fpu
# NONE for Cortex-M0/M0+/M3

# float-abi


# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)
```

I also commented out `$(FPU)` and `$(FLOAT-ABI)`, but the error still exists.
Although I can compile the project without any problems (because gcc has no complaints), but these errors are kind of on my nerve.

Is there a way to fix these errors? Or is there any gcc-based LSPs to use instead of clangd?

There's also [ccls](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#ccls) on neovim's LSP list but I was unable to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> s there a way to fix these errors?

https://clangd.llvm.org/config#files You can:

- create clangd configuration file
- specify `-sysroot` command to specify the location of your buildchain (`/usr/arm-none-eabi/` on my system)
- and other needed options (`-isysroot` `-nostdlib` etc.) if you use them.

I would advise anyway to move CMake and generate compile_command.json anyway.

> is there any gcc-based LSPs to use instead of clangd?

I am not aware of any.

Comment: how should I specify the toolchain folder with `-sysroot`? I didn't find any examples.

Comment: `CompileFlags:
  Add: [-sysroot=the_path_to_your_compiler_toolchain_sysroot]`. Around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866650/clang-cross-compilation-with-arm-none-eabi

Comment: I created `~/.config/clangd/config.yaml` with the option above and clean built the project but the error still appears.

Comment: OK. I added a comma and the header file error is fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Both errors are fixed. I used `--sysroot=/usr/arm-none-eabi ,` and `-mfloat-abi=soft ,` options in the config file.

Comment: An alternative way to get clangd to find the correct headers of a cross-compiler is `--query-driver`, as described in https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc. (Note, unlike `-sysroot`, this is an argument to clangd itself. It causes clangd to query the built-in includes of the compiler that appears in the commands of the `compile_commands.json`)